# How to erase the broadcast that lasts when the app is closed , since I don't want to receive them when I restart the app

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have a launch activity which contains a broadcastReceiver, where I will start a service to download a key file which will send a broadcast when the operation is done . During the app, several downloading operations will be taken, and there is also other receivers somewhere. I just care the first downloading in launch activity and it will be finish when done.

Question: Everytime I restart my app , the broadcast from last time will disrupt the plan. How can I get rid of them .

Comment: Are you using sticky Broadcasts? If you revert to 'normal' ones.

Comment: @RvdK thanks,but the broadcast is also supposed to be received in other activities . soooo.. any other way ?

Comment: If you use normal Broadcasts they will be delivered to all listeners. Also only 1 Activity is alive, so why do others need it aswell? You probably need to think on your design.

Comment: @RvdK Ok,I'm using sticky Broadcasts , since they are needed in others activities. And using normal Broadcasts is a way to my question there . What I wonder now is if the sticky Broadcasts can be erased when the app restart. Is that available in android?

Comment: unregsiterReceiver in `onPause()`

Comment: @MuhammadBabar I did.Also in onStop and onDestory. It doesn't work.I think using removeStickyBroadcast at the everyplace I register a receiver may be the only way .

Answer (score 0):

You can remove a sticky Broadcast with :

```
public abstract void removeStickyBroadcast (Intent intent)
```

(More info: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#removeStickyBroadcast(android.content.Intent )